# how to implement excel sheet values in anylogic software agent based modeling in time plot with the normal distribution?

Tags: anylogic, agent-based-modeling

In AnyLogic software, I am developing an agent-based simulation of cars and components. I have three agents: Main, which is responsible for plotting all the data, Cars, which consists of 100 individual car agents, and Component, which represents a single component agent associated with each car.

To import data from an Excel sheet, I am using the following code:

`input.getCellNumericValue("UseScenario",3,3)/365;`

and i have funtion in car agent which is :-

```
km_normalDistbn = normal(1, main.KmPerDay); 

if (km_added_PerAgent <= main.LifetimeMileage)
{
main.km_all += km_normalDistbn; 
km_added_PerAgent += km_normalDistbn; 


}
else {

}
```

In the Main agent, I have a time plot component where I want to display the value of km_added_PerAgent for the first car (cars(0).km_added_PerAgent).

However, after 365 days, I want to plot a value of 10000 because the average daily distance (main.KmPerDay) is 27.39.

Comment: and... your problem is? I cannot see a question here :)

Comment: In my AnyLogic simulation of cars and components, I have a variable in the Component agent that counts repairs. When displayed on the main dashboard, it shows the count for all 100 cars. How can I display the repair count for only one car on the main dashboard?

Comment: can't see a problem with your setup, code looks fine. Best add more details (screenshots) of the setup... and try to figure out where the issue is with `traceln()` commands as well, maybe you can narrow it down